# Is there any way to make different event listener asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, event-listener

I'm new to js and I'm having troubles with event listner chaining.

This is abstract version of my project.
setTimeout() is not in real project. It is just used to make some task to take long time in example code below.

index.html

```html
<body>
    <div id="dv">
        <button id="btn">click here</button>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="index.js"></script>
```

index.js

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", e=>{
    console.log("(1) first")
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("(2) task which takes longer but must done earlier")
    }, 200);
})

document.getElementById("dv").addEventListener("click", e=>{
    console.log("(3) third")
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("(4) next task")
    }, 100);
})
```

I want to make my code to console.log like this:

```
(1) first
(2) task which takes longer but must done earlier
(3) third
(4) next task
```

but the result is,

```
(1) first
(3) third
(4) next task
(2) task which takes longer but must done earlier
```

How can I make event listener wait until another event listener is done?
I tried to put third parameter of addEventListner which controls bubbling/capturing but it didn't worked.

Comment: Let the first event listener set a (global) variable to a promise, which gets resolved on (2). The second event listener then chains that promise.

Comment: The tasks in the listeners in your real code, are they really asynchronous, or do they block until done?

Comment: @Teemu They are asynchronous. They are codes for server api (ex : await fetch()).

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. How can you control the user behavior based on click on different elements? If the user clicks the button first, that code will execute first and vice versa.

Comment: @code There is a button tag whose id is "btn", and it has event of printing (1) and (2). There is also a div tag whose id is "dv" and contains "btn", and it has event of printing (3) and (4). When I click on button, two event listener executes at the same time(I guess). But I want to make event listener in "btn" executes first, and when it is done, then executes event listener in "dv".

Comment: @Juyeon Nothing is executed at the same time in JS, the event is just bubbling from the button to the parent. Deceze's suggestion works here, only that in the div listener you've to first check, that it was the button which was clicked, otherwise return immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Write a function to generate a bunch of promises with their resolvers and await them using async eventlisteners. If you click on div 2, it wont fire unless 1 was clicked. 3 will wait for BOTH 1 and 2. Obviously if you need to fire only once, you need to do the clean up via `removeEventListener` or set a flag to true (if true, return early from the listener and do nothing).

```js
function genRes(n){
    let prom = Promise.resolve(),arr = [];
    while(--n >= 0){
        let obj = {};
        obj.prom = new Promise(res => obj.res = res);
        prom = prom.then(() => obj.prom);
        arr.push(obj)
    }
    return arr;
}

ress = genRes(2);

document.getElementById("one").addEventListener("click", async function(){
  console.log("one");
  ress[0].res(1);
});

//whenever you are ready call the next resolver ress[n](whatever value)
document.getElementById("two").addEventListener("click", async function(){
  await ress[0].prom;
  console.log("two");
  ress[1].res("hey");
});

document.getElementById("three").addEventListener("click", async function(){
  let result = await ress[1].prom; //hey
  console.log("three");
});
```

```css
#one {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}

#two {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

#three {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
<div id="three"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand why you need two event listeners and are attemtping to make the bubbling of events wait for a promise to complete. One listener that does not propagate and a chaining of promises might provide what you appear to be looking to accomplish. Or, I may be completely misunderstanding your objective.

This code sample may help illustrate.

You can also read these documents.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#chained_promises

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/Promise

```js
function task_200() {
 return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("(2) task which takes longer but must done earlier");
        resolve('success from task_200');
}, 200);
  });
}

function task_100() {
 return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
 setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("(4) next task");
        resolve('success from task_100');
    }, 100);
 });
}

document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", e=>{
    console.log("(1) first");
    e.stopPropagation();

task_200()
 .then( (result) => {console.log(result); return task_100();}, (error) => {console.log(error);} )
 .then( (result) => {console.log(result);}, (error) => {console.log(error);} )
});

document.getElementById("dv").addEventListener("click", e=>{
console.log("(3) third")
});
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="dv">
        <button id="btn">click here</button>
    </div>
</body>
```